How to make the Android app icon “cover” rather than “contain”?
In flutter I use `flutter_launcher_iconsˋ to generate my app icons, from the picture I’ve made but the result is like it used “contain” rather the expected “cover” mode as follows:

Is there a way to tell the plugin to fix this?
Or any other way to handle this is very welcome!
Note that the iOS version is just perfect.
[UPATE] The (desired) result I get on iOS


Related: https://developer.android.com/distribute/google-play/resources/icon-design-specifications but you may want to add to your post the iOS icon. Also be aware of existing issues for  https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_launcher_icons/issues

I added the iOS result which I want to get on Android as well
